how can i use swiperjs to make the arrows work as intended
I am trying to make a website using html,css and js, and i try using swiperjs to make the arrows work but i cant seem to catch it. From what i tried, i can make the "Sports" movable from left to right or vice-versa, but i cant make the arrows look the same. The sports needs to be seen 3 on the screen, and another number added so that when you press right for example, it will show the next sport.
I am expecting to make the arrows work as intented, and still look how i want them to look.
what i triedhow i want them to look

If the arrows can work without the swiperjs, it will be all right too.

You can place your arrows anywhere and style them how you like, you will just need to connect them to your slider like this:
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  navigation: {
    prevEl: ".my-prev-arrow",
    nextEl: ".my-next-arrow",
  }
});

See docs for more information and examples.

Thanks so much, in the near future when I will encounter this problem again i Will try doing as you told me, but right now I created a personalized carousel so right now it works, so thanks a lot
